# Assign property a value if its not equal to this value shorthand

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

If I have a code like this

```
if (mode != EntryMode.View)
{
    mode = EntryMode.View;
}
```

Does it have a simpler way of writing it like the coalesce operator ?

More Info:

I have `MainMode` and `SubMode` should I set `MainMode` to View the `SubMode` should be set to View, if its not equal to View already, but I can't simply set `SubMode` to View because this will execute lots of actions that have been already executed if `SubMode` was set to View before, that why I have to check if its set to View to prevent those actions from being executed again.

```
    private EntryMode _mainMode;
    private EntryMode _subMode;

    EntryMode MainMode
    {
        get => _mainMode;
        set
        {
            _mainMode = value;
            if (value == EntryMode.View)
            {
                if (SubMode != EntryMode.View)
                {
                    SubMode = EntryMode.View;
                }

                // do some stuff
            }
        }
    }

    EntryMode SubMode
    {
        get => _subMode;
        set
        {
            _subMode = value;

            if (value == EntryMode.View)
            {
                // do some stuff once
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just do `mode = EntryMode.View`? Removing the `if` statement will have no bearing on the outcome here.

Comment: when I set mode to view there a lots of things that happens so its important to tell if the mode is already set to view or not so that I don't have to do this things again.

Comment: Is `mode` a property or a field? (It's oddly named if it's a property.) More context would really help here.

Comment: Is `mode` a property whose code is under your control? Then you could add a check in its setter method `if (mode != value) {// Do the expensive stuff}` and you'd eliminate the overhead everwhere the property is set.

Comment: "I can't simply set SubMode to View because this will execute lots of actions that have been already executed if SubMode was set to View before" - it sounds to me like that's the problem. Your `SubMode` property should probably check whether `_subMode == value` at the start of the setter and return if so.

Comment: _"when I set mode to view there a lots of things that happens"_ The overarching advice here is to _not_ add that behavior to the setter of a property. Setter logic is to be generally avoided specifically because it tends to create such a house of cards for your logical flow.

Comment: @Flater Care to elaborate "house of cards for your logical flow", please ?

Comment: @Tima: The approach you've chosen to take leads to very hard to manage code that requires a lot of intricate `if` checks to do precisely what you want it to do, and you risk breaking things when you forget to put all the right checks in place. It's better to avoid tricky logic instead of trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF and WinUi 3 use SetProperty. It returns true when value is not equal to ref value.
You need to write SetProperty on your own or use NuGet Manager > CommunityToolkit.Mvvm https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet

```
public bool Started
{
    get => _started;
    set
    {
        if(SetProperty(ref _started, value))
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StatusBrush));
        }
    }
}
```

I found today I have way too much OnPropertyChanged. And return value of SetProperty is helpful to fix it.